# How can I reset the background images I LIKE for windows 10

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization

Before you point me to the countless answers of how to change backgrounds, here is the above question in DETAIL.

In Windows 10, every morning it comes up with a new photo background asking me if I like the background. If I respond on the upper right part of the screen with a YES, Windows 10 records that I like it and it becomes one of the images in my backgrounds collection and is used in rotation with other images I like.

There were a few images I accidentally said yes to when I meant to say no. Is there a way to reset this rotation to start over or maybe a way I can go back and remove that specific image from my selected images in the collection so that it will no longer be in my collection of backgrounds?

Comment: You write in your question: "every morning it comes up with a new photo background asking me if I like the background". What do you mean by "it"? Do you have installed some application that do it?

Comment: "it" meaning my Windows Machine (version 10).  There is no 3rd  party.  This is what came with my Windows 10.

Comment: Ok, I see, you have activated the Windows Spotlight. Please take a look: http://superuser.com/questions/1043501/reset-windows-spotlight

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper

There might be multiple folders and pictures, delete what you don't want. If you get trusted installer issues:

1. Go to C:\Windows\Web\
2. Right click on Wallpaper, Properties
3. Go to Security tab
4. Click Advanced
5. Go to Owner Tab
6. Click edit
7. Add your own account name instead of TrustedInstaller's
8. check the box Replace owner on sub containers and objects
9. press OK through all your open windows to get back to windows explorer
10. Right click again, Properties
11. Go to security, select your name, click edit
12. Click the allow all checkbox, then OK through everything.

I know this is long but I hope it helps!